# Excluding those in a list with higher length than a fix number

Tags: r, list

Consider this function

```
library(plyr)
all.subsets <- function(set) {
  n <- length(set)
  bin <- expand.grid(rlply(n, c(F, T)))
  mlply(bin, function(...) { set[c(...)] })
}
```

(reference: http://www.r-bloggers.com/generating-all-subsets-of-a-set/)

I am using it as follows:

```
members <- c('a','b','c','d')
subsets <- all.subsets(members)
```

Now, how can I exclude those with `length(subsets[i])` > 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimal change would be to add an additional argument `n_max` to your all.subsets function and filter inside by rowSums:

```
all.subsets <- function(set, max_n) {
  n <- length(set)
  bin <- expand.grid(rlply(n, c(F, T)))
  bin <- bin[rowSums(bin) <= max_n,]
  mlply(bin, function(...) { set[c(...)] })
}


subsets <- all.subsets(members, max_n = 3)
```